I need help with the following fourier transform.
The question ask for the cosine transform of $x^{\alpha -1}$.
So, we have the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha -1}\cos(kx) \,dx,\quad 0<\alpha<1$$
I tried to integrate on the complex plane with $f(z)=\frac{\cos(kx)}{x^{1-\alpha}}$ on a semi-circular contour with an smaller semi-circule with radius $\varepsilon$ in z=0.
I'm about to try other contour (a quarter of a circle with the same smaller semi-circule) and the function $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{1-\alpha}}$. If I get anywhere near the answer, which is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\Gamma (\alpha)\frac{\cos(\alpha \pi /2)}{k^{\alpha}}$, I'll update the post.

Have you tried $e^{ikx}$ instead?

If you use what @TedShifrin suggested, you obtain the result without any complex analysis (s well as the sister integral)..

Its also the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_x\cos (k x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } \cos (k x), x^{\alpha -1} , dx=\cos\left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right), \Gamma(\alpha), \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}},,\quad 0<\Re(\alpha)<1$$ which is the correct answer according to Mathematica.
